# IE10 preserve-3d

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, modernizr

[With IE10 not working directly with preserve-3d](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#the_ms_transform_style_property), I'm failing miserably at adding a test to fall back on this.

I've seen there was a pull request related to this recently integrated into Modernizr, however .preserve3d also seems to do nothing (built from repo).  https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/commit/4c8f8905e0f6487c85c91f4bd67d51b62b40b993

- Checking for specifically IE10 seems very bad.  Can I avoid this?
- Applying MS idea of moving the transform to the children causes interesting results.  I assume that it is not an answer for what I'm trying to do?
- This should work on IE8,9,11(?),Chrome,Firefox,Safari

What I hope to do...

```
 Modernizr.addTest('csstransformspreserve3d', function () {
    var prop = Modernizr.prefixed('transformStyle');
    var val = 'preserve-3d';
    var computedStyle;
    if(!prop) return false;

    prop = prop.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(str,m1){ return '-' + m1.toLowerCase(); }).replace(/^ms-/,'-ms-');

    Modernizr.testStyles('#modernizr{' + prop + ':' + val + ';}', function (el, rule) {
        computedStyle = win.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(prop) : '';
    });

    return (computedStyle === val);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LwaMY/1/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote more general solution for case when you need to check for css **value** support.

Example of use:`Modernizr.addValueTest('transform-style','preserve-3d');`

Demo on [codepen](http://codepen.io/ruddog/pen/iKBet).

Implementation:

```
Modernizr.addValueTest = function(property,value){
    Modernizr.addTest(property+value , function () {
        var element = document.createElement('link');
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
        var properties = [];

        var upcaseProp  = property.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + property.slice(1);
        properties[property] =property;
        properties['Webkit'+upcaseProp] ='-webkit-'+property;
        properties['Moz'+upcaseProp] ='-moz-'+property;
        properties['ms'+upcaseProp] ='-ms-'+property;

        body.insertBefore(element, null);
        for (var i in properties) {
            if (element.style[i] !== undefined) {
                element.style[i] = value;
            }
        }
        //ie7,ie8 doesnt support getComputedStyle
        //so this is the implementation
        if(!window.getComputedStyle) {
            window.getComputedStyle = function(el, pseudo) {
                this.el = el;
                this.getPropertyValue = function(prop) {
                    var re = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g;
                    if (prop == 'float') prop = 'styleFloat';
                    if (re.test(prop)) {
                        prop = prop.replace(re, function () {
                            return arguments[2].toUpperCase();
                        });
                    }
                    return el.currentStyle[prop] ? el.currentStyle[prop] : null;
                };
                return this;
            };
        }

        var st = window.getComputedStyle(element, null),
            currentValue = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-"+property) ||
                st.getPropertyValue("-moz-"+property) ||
                st.getPropertyValue("-ms-"+property) ||
                st.getPropertyValue(property);

        if(currentValue!== value){
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            return false;
        }
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        return true;
    });
}
```